# Im trying to test a equality

Tags: symbolic, summation

I'm trying to test

```
Sum[(-1)^(n + 1)/(3 n + 6 (-1)^n), {n, 0, Infinity}] == 1/3 (Log[2] - 1)
```

but I don't get an answer, just the reprint of the above. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you mean to sum up to $\infty$?  Then use the symbol `Infinity`, not `oo`.  If Mathematica returns a `Sum` unchanged, it means that it cannot compute it symbolically.

Comment: @Szabolcs using Infinity is the same.

Comment: But the meaning of your question, *as you wrote it*, it not the same.

Comment: If you try summing a very large number of terms, it doesn't disprove your hypothesis: `Total@Table[(-1)^(n + 1)/(N[n] + 2 (-1)^n), {n, 0, 100000}]` and check `N[Log[2]-1]` .

Comment: @Szabolcs there is a numerical test with some error range or so? Other than the last example you put.

Comment: Add adjacent pairs, `Together` to get a single term, then sum. This removes all the powers of -1. `In[951]:= Simplify[
 1/3*Sum[Together[1/(n + 2) - 1/((n + 1) - 2)], {n, 0, Infinity, 2}]]

Out[951]= 1/3 (1 - Log[2])` (I tried with the correct sign but it does not simplify to the desired form).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following Daniel Lichtblau's approach

```
t[n_] = (-1)^(n + 1)/(3 n + 6 (-1)^n);

t2[n_] = t[2 n] + t[2 n + 1] // Simplify[#, Element[n, Integers]] &

(*  1/(2*(-1 + n + 2*n^2))  *)

Sum[t2[n], {n, 0, Infinity}] // PowerExpand // Simplify

(*  (1/3)*(-1 + Log[2])  *)
```

**EDIT:** Structuring as an equality test

```
Sum[t2[n], {n, 0, Infinity}] == (Log[2] - 1)/3

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Ah, very interesting, thank you. This is not a test but it is certainly useful to know how to do this manipulations when other forms of evaluation dont work directly.